# Modulel in Zend Framework don't work

Tags: zend-framework

I have a problem in creating a modular application with zend framework, I followed more tutorials and modules studied several times, but I always get the same error.

The structure of my application is in the following figure.

+Site

- application

  +configs

  +modules

  ```
    admin

    default
  ```

  +Bootstrap.php
- docs
- library
- public
- test

In each module I have a class that extends the class Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap, and are respectively:

- Admin_Bootstrap
- Default_Bootstrap

My application.ini file is as follows:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

;module support
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
resources.frontController.defaultModule="default"
;end module support
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

If I try to get to the url `http://localhost/site.it/public/` it's ok, but if i try to get to the url `http://localhost/site.it/public/admin`  I get the error The requested URL `http://localhost/site.it/public/admin` was not found on this server.

The file .htaccess is composed of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have a htaccess file in public? If so please edit your question to include its contents.

Comment: Yes I have .htaccess file

Comment: It's a generic 404 error no?  Sounds like folder permissions or host setup.  Backtrack.  Try something simple like an index.html in your site's root and nothing else.  Can you browse to that?

Comment: There are no mistakes inserting an index.html file in the root of the application

Comment: Sounds like your htaccess file is not being used. Check your vhost configuration for the `AllowOverride` directive.

Comment: I have not configured any vhost for the application of which we speak.

Answer (score 0):

You better use an alias like siteit.localhost or something so you don't need to write public everytime. This may solve your problem but i need to add something; in module admin, do controllers have Admin before their name?

like

```
class Admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {...
```

By the way in our code we include every folder in module like this, (remove the subview line if you don't use subviews)

```
define('ROOT_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'));

$modules = array('admin', 'foo' , 'asdasd');

foreach ($modules as $module) {
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/application/modules/' . $module . '/models');
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/application/modules/' . $module . '/forms');
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/application/modules/' . $module . '/views');
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/application/modules/' . $module . '/controllers');
    $subview->addBasePath(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/application/modules/' . $module . '/views');
}
```

Comment: It is the controller of the modules start with NameModule_ .

Comment: In your admin folder there has to be a folder named controllers and there should be at least one controller named IndexController.php which's class definition must be like my answer. Do you have any controller in your admin module? i can add folder structure if you want.

Comment: I will in any module everything you need, I followed all tutorials and guides that explain how to do. But I was not able to resolve the situation.